# Django date__range query- add 1 day if date range ends on current date

Tags: django, date, view, filter

On my site I have a page where you can enter a start and end date via a javascript calendar widget. It will query the database and return the results. Here is my view

```
class flagfilter(ListView, View):
form_class = FlagReportForm
template_name = 'free/flagreport.html'
paginate_by = 20

def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(None)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})


def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        start_date = request.POST.get('start_date', '')
        end_date = request.POST.get('end_date', '')
        user = request.user
        s = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(start_date), '%m/%d/%Y')
        e = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(end_date), '%m/%d/%Y')
        if e == s:
            e = e + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
        s_filtered = s.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        e_filtered = e.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        punch = Punch.objects.filter(date__range=[str(s_filtered),str(e_filtered)]).order_by('-date')
        punches = punch.filter(user=user)
        context = {'punches': punches}
        return render(request, 'free/flagreport2.html', context)

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

My issue is if you have a date range that ends on today's date it wont return objects from the current day. I added this line:

```
        if e == s:
        e = e + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
```

I did this because if you have the start and end date as the current date it wouldn't return today's punch objects. This fixed the issue but I still have a problem. If you enter a date range with a start date of the, lets say, last week sometime. And the end date is the current day. It still wont return the current days punch object. So I would like to replace this code with something that checks if the end date is the current date, and if so, add an additional day to the end date. I have tried a few things but can't get any to work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just noticed that the same thing happens regardless of the date selected as the end date. The end date results do not get returned. So adding

```
e = e + datetime.timedelta(days=)
```

should fix my issue!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
Punch.objects.filter(date__gte=s, date__lte=e).order_by('-date')
```

instead of date__range, I think that should save you having to use strftime and any timedelta stuff

Edit: I don't think Q is even needed

Comment: The strmstime stuff is to convert the format of my widget into what Django likes. But I've never seen the code you just shared. I'll have to do some reading about it!

Comment: The idea is to use gte and lte (greater than or equal/less than equal) so the query goes where data >= 2017-01-01 and date <= 2017-01-30 rather than date >= 2017-01-01 and date < 2017-01-30. The less than equal should make it so you don't have to deal with adding extra days

Comment: Thanks for the info!